# Grow 3D array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix-indexing

Is there a way to grow a 3D array in the third dimension using the `end` index in a loop in Matlab?

In 2D it can be done like

```
a = [];
for x = y
   a(end + 1, :) = f(x);
end
```

But in 3D the same thing will not work as `a(1,1,end)` will try to index `a(1,1,1)` the first iteration (not `a(1,1,0)` as one might expect). So I can't do

```
im = [];
for x = y
   im(:, :, end + 1) = g(x);
end
```

It seems the `end` of `a` in third dimension is handled a bit differently than in the first two:

```
>> a = [];
>> a(end,end,end) = 1
Attempted to access a(0,0,1); index must be a positive integer or logical.
```

Am I missing something about how `end` indexing works here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What you're asking...

If you know the size of g(x), initialize `im` to an empty 3d-array:

```
im = zeros(n, m, 0);   %instead of im = [];
```

I think your code should work now.

#### A better way...

Another note, resizing arrays each iteration is *expensive*! This doesn't really matter if the array is small, but for huge matrices, there can be a big performance hit.

I'd initialize to:

```
im = zeros(n, m, length(y));
```

And then index appropriately. For example:

```
i = 1;
for x = y
   im(:, :, i) = g(x);
   i = i + 1;
end
```

This way you're not assigning new memory and copying over the *whole* matrix `im` each time it gets resized!

Comment: Good idea about the initialization! If fact it seems to work even without knowing the size of g(x), so just doing im = zeros(0,0,0) works fine.